# On stackexchange.com, sub-tabs (votes recent newest added) in Favorites tab in use profile are served standalone without outer template or css

Tags: bug, network-profile

On stackexchange.com if you goto your profile and under the favourites tab, click on one of the sub tabs (votes recent newest added)

[image]

If you middle click or ctrl click it so as to get that particular tab's URL

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/favorites/<USER-ID>?page=1&sort=added
```

it serves you an unstyled HTML without the rest of the site's template around it.

Note: This only happens on stackexchange.com. On other sites it works like it should.

Comment: No repro, working fine for me showing the full page. What browser?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just noticed it's only happening on stackexchange.com, other sites work fine

Comment: Yep. But it's not limited to favorites tab, it's the same in all tabs having a sub filter.